# Smallest smart tracking device for locating objects, alternative to TrackR

Tags: gps, passive-tracker, tracking-devices

I'm looking for thinnest tracking device such as [TrackR sticker](https://www.thetrackr.com/sticker) to be able to tag multiple objects, then track them down using some smart app. For example for organizing or locating the lost items. So basically it should allow me to apply a unique name. Item ringer (ring activated by app) would be an advantage.

I've been using TrackR, but I had some [issues](https://iot.stackexchange.com/q/238/271) when item ringer was activated by itself.

So I'm curious if there are some alternatives to it.

Comment: You could always try the highly-revered [RFID powder](http://www.engadget.com/2007/02/14/hitachis-rfid-powder-freaks-us-the-heck-out/). ;)

Comment: I've been using [Duet by Protag](http://theprotag.com/sg-en/), but I have also experienced similar issues with the device going off by itself on rare occasions so I wouldn't consider it a definite recommendation. Might still be worth checking out if nothing else came up